# What is the word to indicate that a thought has been repeatedly occurring to me since 2 days?

Tags: single-word-requests

A particular came to my mind after a work related meeting, and it has been consistently occurring to me since then. I want to say "*This thought has been -----------ing since last 2 days*"

I thought about using the word: "Pestering", but its meaning "trouble or annoy (someone) with frequent or persistent requests or interruptions." seems to have a negative connotation.

A negative connotation is not what I am experiencing. It was repeatedly occurring in a positive sense really. How do I express this?

Comment: Does "particular" mean a feeling, a word, a thought, a phrase?

Comment: Perhaps *haunt, linger, loiter, etc.?*

Comment: I am sorry, but I have to VTC as "unclear what you are asking". Is this a "thought", or a "feeling"? They really are different things. Possibly it is a feeling caused by the recurring thought?

Comment: echoing is a possibility

Answer (score 4):

The word *recurring* can be used both for positive and negative things:

> This thought has been recurring to me for the past 2 days.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/recurring) provides a positive/neutral and a negative usage:

> 1 Occurring again periodically or repeatedly.
>   *‘gratitude is a recurring theme in the book’*
>
> 1.1 (of a thought, image, or memory) repeatedly coming back to a person's mind.
>   *‘they are haunted by a recurring image of their daughter on the night she died’*

but I'm pretty sure thoughts can be positively recurring as well.

Answer (score 1):

Persisting.

‘This thought has been persisting for the last two days’ (note - you cannot say ‘since last 2 days’, that’s not correct).

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/persistence